# Set SVG data as cursor

Tags: javascript, css, svg, cursor

## I want to change the cursor via jquery

The problem is I dont want any external files or sources.
I also want it to be a SVG so I thought this would work:

```
$("html").css("cursor: url('<svg><circle cx="5.7" cy="6.2" r="6"/></svg>'), auto");
```

but it didnt :(

I konw there are already a lot of threads about cursor open but none of them with direct SVG data.

Thx in advance

PS: Is it possible to animate that data dynamically ?

Comment: I don't know if it will work but your jQuery code is invalid. You need to pass 2 parameters to the `css` function. Try `"$("html").css("cursor", "url('<svg><circle cx="5.7" cy="6.2" r="6"/></svg>'), auto");
`

Comment: That's not a url you're providing. You either need to point to an external svg file or a data url (part of which would be the data you've already got). Note that your data is missing the SVG namespace and it will need that to be valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question and there are two ways to solve it:

1) Create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) url and pass the svg data and pass the url to the property value

2) Use a data url, but there is a catch - if you don't specify dimensions then the cursor won't change as the browser doesn't know what size to make it. Furthermore you need to add the `xmlns` tags or the browser still won't display it.

Note that I've used ES6 strings for brevity but if you are not using a transpiler/want to support old browsers then change to string concatenation.

```js
function svgUrl(svgString, width, height, viewBoxWidth, viewBoxHeight) {
  viewBoxWidth = viewBoxWidth || width;
  viewBoxHeight = viewBoxHeight || width;
  return `url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="${width}" height="${height}" viewBox="0 0 ${viewBoxWidth} ${viewBoxHeight}">${svgString}</svg>')`;
}

$('html').css('cursor', `${svgUrl('<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100"/>', 100, 100, 200, 200)}, auto`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS you could also use a base64 string if you're worried about invalid characters in the svg data:

```
function svgToBase64Url(svgString, width, height) {
  const base64SVG = btoa(`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="${width}px" height="${height}px">${svgString}</svg>`);
  return `url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64SVG}')`;
}
```

Comment: Generally you just need to encode # as %23 to avoid it being interpreted as a fragment identifier. That's usually the only invalid character in a utf8 data url

Comment: Thx man works great !
But what does the width and height really control because it doesnt work if I set it to 200 ? 
And Is it possible to get the "hitpoint" cursor to be in the middle of the circle ?
Btw thx for calling this a good question

Comment: @sanojLeOne see my edited snippet - svg has some confusing viewBox properties you'd need to adjust too (as well as the circle values themselves)

Comment: Might be clearer if you experiment here: https://jsfiddle.net/rz8zreq2/

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed use SVG for cursors, but you'll need to save the SVG as its own file, and reference it:

```
cursor: url('/path/to/your/graphic.svg');
```

Comment: No you don't, you can use a data url.